# SoapUI change milliseconds value in delay step with groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

I would like to mass update existing delay steps in SoapUI with groovy that have the value 1000 milliseconds.

New value should be:
${=(int)(Math.random()*10000)}

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SoapUI project file is an XML file. You can replace values in that file with Groovy like this:

```
def projectFileA = new File('/path/to/your/soapui-project.xml')
def projectFileB = projectFileA.text.replaceAll('your old string', 'your new string')
projectfileA.text = projectfileB
```

If you don't have a Groovy IDE setup you can use groovyConsole, or you can try it in SoapUI itself.